# How do I position my game over menu so it looks the same in every iOS device on Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm making a game for the iPhone and iPad and I don't understand how when I position my menu on the iPhone 5s it looks different on the iPad. Like my score it is set perfectly in the score menu on  the 5s and 4 and 5 but in the iPad its a little lower and not the same positioning. How do I fix this? Thanks! I  use this code to position my menus:

```
    endOfGameHighScoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 1.8, 
    self.size.height / 2.7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahm with `self.size.width` you don't get the size of the view but the label?

I would recommend to create a view containing all the game over stuff you need and then position the center of it in the view's center:

```
gameOverView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width/2, self.view.frame.height/2)
```